# Subtitle TableView Cell

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, subtitle

I am trying to get two texts in the title of the cell using the subtitle style. I tried "cell.textLabel!.text = data.valueForKeyPath("divelocation, divenumber") as? String" with no luck.

can anyone help?  thanks

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {


    // Configure the cell...

    let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID as String)! as! UITableViewCell

    if let ip = indexPath{

        var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as! NSManagedObject
        cell.textLabel!.text = data.valueForKeyPath("divelocation, divenumber") as? String

        var ddate = data.valueForKeyPath("divedate") as! String
        var dnumber = data.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") as! String

        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(dnumber) date: \(ddate)"
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you seeing `textLabel` correctly, and only `detailTextLabel` is not appearing? What cell type did you specify in you prototype cell?

Comment: If I have cell.textLabel!.text = data.valueForKeyPath("divelocation") as? String then everything works, I just want to add dive number beside dive location.  I am using the subtitle cell in the Prototype cell

Comment: @Scubadivingfool Should it not be "divelocation.divenumber" for your key path?

Comment: OK, let's step back. You question's title says that there's a problem in the subtitle (i.e. the `detailTextLabel`). But after reading your comment, I'm re-reading your question, it looks like the problem is in the `textLabel` not `detailTextLabel`. So, please edit your question and clarify what precisely the issue is. Frankly, the keypath `divelocation, divenumber` looks highly suspect to me: What are you trying to do there? Are those two separate fields? Why aren't you handling it like you did `divedate` and `divenumber`?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are the table view and index path variables optional? You can save yourself the unwrapping of an optional that is not optional. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the style as `UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {


// Configure the cell...

let CellID: NSString = "Cell"
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID as String)! as! UITableViewCell

if let ip = indexPath{

    var data: NSManagedObject = myList[ip.row] as! NSManagedObject
    var divelocation = data.valueForKeyPath("divelocation") as! String
    var divenumber = data.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") as! String
    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(divelocation)" + "\(divenumber)"

    var ddate = data.valueForKeyPath("divedate") as! String
    var dnumber = data.valueForKeyPath("divenumber") as! String

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(dnumber) date: \(ddate)"
}
return cell
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not seeing how you would set what text goes in the labels.

Comment: @Scubadivingfool I understood,  edited the answer . hope it helps

Comment: Or `cell.textLabel!.text = "\(divelocation), \(divenumber)"`.

Answer (score -1):

When init cells you must init like this

```
var cell_ : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL_ID") as? UITableViewCell
    if(cell_ == nil)
    {
        cell_ = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CELL_ID")
    }
```

Comment: It's a little strong to say that one "must" do it that way. Yes, you have to do that if you don't use prototypes and you don't register NIB or class with the identifier. Frankly, this pattern of manually instantiating a cell is no longer common practice (though perfectly acceptable if you want to do it that way). Needless to say, this is unlikely to be the OP's problem, otherwise his forced unwrapping would have caused his app to crash and surely he would have told us if that happened.

Comment: Ok, programmatically let you do managing all the creation of the cell, nib sometimes do strange things :P